# ASP.NET MVC - Parámetro en View Bag

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, http-get

Hola amigos quiero crear un get que me devuelva en una vista un parametro que estoy mandando por la url, esto es lo que intento

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult TTry(String i)
    {
        ViewBag.ID_I = i;
        return View("about");
    }
```

y mi vista

```
   @{
        ViewBag.Title = "About";
    }
    <h2>@ViewBag.ID_I</h2>
```

entonces mando algo como

> localhost:mipuerto/micontroller/TTry/micuerda

Pero cuando inspecciono `i` me dice que el objeto esta vacio, ¿alguien sabe a qué se deba?

Comment: Hola, indica en la pregunta lo que tienes en el archivo de rutas RouteConfig.cs

Answer (score 2):

En tu archivo de rutas `RouteConfig.cs` seguramente tengas definida la **ruta por defecto**:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

La cual acepta un parámetro opcional con el nombre **id**.

En tu Acción `TTry` tienes un parámetro de entrada llamado **i** `(String i)`, que no coincide con el **parámetro opcional** de la ruta (**id**).

Para solucionarlo renombra el parámetro de la Acción a **id**:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult TTry(String id)
{
    ViewBag.ID_I = id;
    return View("about");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Otra opción que tienes es definir directamente en el controlador la ruta a la que vas a acceder:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("TTry/{i:string}")] 
public ActionResult TTry(String i){

}
```